# How does Spring Security LDAP protect password during Active Directory authentication?

Tags: spring-security, active-directory

With reference to class `org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`, used to perform Active Directory authentication in all of our web applications, I have been asked the following question by our customer, which poses me a doubt:

> What is the security protocol used during authentication – LDAP SSL / NTLM / KERBEROS ?
> If you are just using LDAP and not LDAPS (secure LDAP) then it would be a concern as we would then be transmitting credentials in clear text between the web server and Active Directory.

Example configuration:

```
    <b:bean id="adAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <b:constructor-arg value="${ldap.domain}" />
        <b:constructor-arg value="${ldap.url}" />
        <b:property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="adUserDetailsContextMapper" />
        <b:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="false" />
    </b:bean>
```

Now that I think about it, none of us in my development team ever cared about the security of the AD password (most of our customers don't even enforce SSL).

I can't find reference on Spring documentation. Spring Security LDAP version is 3.2.5

Does somebody know **if** and **how** Spring LDAP protects password when authenticating against Active Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) said the password is sent **plaintext** with those settings