# How to secure Spring Security's ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider network interactions

Tags: spring-security, active-directory

From my own inspection of the source and everything I have so far read, Spring Security's ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ldap-active-directory) interacts with ActiveDirectory "in the clear"...passwords are transmitted using plain text.

I have see questions such as [How does Spring Security LDAP protect password during Active Directory authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27822824/3631003), but this only confirms my concern. My google-fu has not been good enough for me to have found a clear solution as yet.

I am working with a utility that is tightening up security significantly and I don't believe that my current use of ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider (with plaintext passwords) will be acceptable for much longer.

I currently use AD to authenticate a user and to validate that the presented user has been granted a role that lets them use the application making the request.

(I am not above ripping Spring Security out if I have to, but I strongly suspect that my managers' fear factor would increase quite significantly if I brought this to them, so I am looking for a minimal change, if such is at all possible...)

I believe the AD instance is Windows Server 2008 R2.

I am using ldap://...:389. My attempt to use ldaps://...:636 fails (but i don't currently have the exact message to hand; it's the weekend...apologies).

I can't believe that I am the only person out there with this need, so is there anyone out there with experience that can point me towards the 'canonical' solution?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the domain controller has an SSL certificate installed? It won't listen on 636 until that happens, and there is no cert by default.

Answer (score 0):

Had used spring-ldap module to achieve your requirement.
What I did was :

```
    <bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    </bean>
   <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
        <property name="url" value="--ldaps url goes here" />
        <property name="userDn"
            value="--user dn goes here" />
        <property name="password"
            value="--password goes here" />
    </bean>
```

In one of the service classes autowired  ldapTemplate.
Had a method which looked something like this:

```
  public boolean authenticate(final String username, final String password)
            throws MyException {
           //searchAttribute is bean attribute here
            final String searchQuery = "(" + searchAttribute + "=" + username + ")";
            boolean status = false;
            AuthenticationErrorCallback callback = new SpringLdapAuthenticationErrorCallback();
            try {
                status = ldapTemplate.authenticate(basePath, searchQuery, password,
                        callback);
                if (!status) {

                    LOGGER.error("Error while ldap authencation" + callback);
                    throw new MyException(
                            ErrorEnum.INVALID_USER.getCode(),
                            ErrorEnum.INVALID_USER.getDescription());

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.error("Error while ldap authencation" + ex);
                throw new  MyException(ErrorEnum.INVALID_USER.getCode(),
                        ErrorEnum.INVALID_USER.getDescription());
            }
            return status;
```

When using ldaps you should take care to add ldap servers certificate to your truststore. Since most of the time it would be a self signed certificate.
Also check if server support anonymous authentication.
If it does not then you will need a user which will first bind to ldap
and then authenticate the incoming request.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks to the answerers. I am still working through the process of importing certificates and CAs. There doesn't seem to be anyone in the organisation that can point me to a known answer, so I am (slowly, with low bandwidth) working the issue the long way. I will report back when I know something concrete.